# OnClick for item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I am witnessing a wierd behavior of `RecyclerView`. so I have set an OnClickListener in the `ViewHolder` on a `Button` which is meant to do 3 things, when the user clicks:

1. Add the current item's data to an `ArrayList` [displayed on a different `Fragment`]
2. Display a `Toast` to the user.
3. modify the UI of the selected item. [i.e setVisibility of Button to `View.INVISIBLE` etc..]

now, while the first two tasks of the `OnClickListener` are fulfilled successfully and apply **only** to the selected item, the third one which is meant to modify the UI of the **selected** item only, instead gets also applied to each 9th Item on the `RecyclerView`.

1. How do I  prevent this behavior?
2. Why is this behavior occurring with the 3rd task only?

**i.e** from previous answers on this. particular topic that I saw, I got the notion that it's better to insert the `OnClickListener` in the `ViewHolder` rather then putting it in `onBindViewHolder`, which did not solve the issue. I have followed other suggestions on stackOverflow and all failed.

Here is my code:

```
static class ItemsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsRecyclerAdapter.ItemsViewHolder>{

    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;
    List<ProductItem> data;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int id;
    private int shopCode;

    public ItemsRecyclerAdapter(List<ProductItem> data, FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, int id, int shopCode) {
        this.fragmentActivity = fragmentActivity;
        this.data = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(fragmentActivity);
        this.id = id;
        this.shopCode = shopCode;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pricing_item, parent, false);

        return new ItemsViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductItem itemPrice = data.get(position);
        holder.productName.setText(itemPrice.getProductName());
        holder.quantity.setText(itemPrice.getProductQuantity());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(itemPrice.getproductPrice());
        Picasso.with(fragmentActivity).load(itemPrice.getThumbUrl()).into(holder.imgProduct);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


        class ItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView productName, quantity, tvPrice;
        ImageView imgProduct;
        Button btnAddToBasket, btnAdd, btnRemove;

        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(fragmentActivity.getAssets(), "fonts/Assistant-SemiBold.ttf");

        public ItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
            tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            imgProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProduct);
            btnAddToBasket = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddToBasket);
            btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnRemove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

            btnAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnRemove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            quantity.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
            productName.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
            tvPrice.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

            Typeface fontAwesomeBasketIcon = Typeface.createFromAsset(fragmentActivity.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
            btnAddToBasket.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);
            btnAdd.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);
            btnRemove.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);



            btnAddToBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = getAdapterPosition();

                    MyBasketFragment.myBasketList
                            .add(new ProductItem(data.get(pos).getProductName(), data.get(pos).getProductQuantity(),
                                    data.get(pos).getproductPrice(), data.get(pos).getThumbUrl(), id, shopCode));

                    btnAddToBasket.setOnClickListener(null);


                    Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, "New product..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    btnAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                }
            });

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ItemsFragment.atomic.incrementAndGet();
                    btnAddToBasket.setText(String.valueOf(atomic.get()));
                }
            });
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is why you should use recyclerview. Listview initiliazes only shown childs that means if you scroll down, lets say sixth item will be first item because of its the first showing item. So you should use recyclerview and ask to us about your weird recyclerview problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every Click of an item, I assign a boolean in the instantiated object to true and and then I run `notifyDataSetChanged()` which. updates all items with data objects which have a `boolean` true. this way I'm ensuring that **only** the selected object will be updated.

It looks something like this:

**ViewHolder**

```
    class ItemsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView productName, quantity, tvPrice;
        ImageView imgProduct;
        Button btnAddToBasket, btnAdd, btnRemove;

        Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(fragmentActivity.getAssets(), "fonts/Assistant-SemiBold.ttf");

        public ItemsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
            quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
            tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
            imgProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgProduct);
            btnAddToBasket = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddToBasket);
            btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnRemove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);

            btnAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnRemove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            quantity.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
            productName.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
            tvPrice.setTypeface(myCustomFont);

            Typeface fontAwesomeBasketIcon = Typeface.createFromAsset(fragmentActivity.getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
            btnAddToBasket.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);
            btnAdd.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);
            btnRemove.setTypeface(fontAwesomeBasketIcon);


        }

        public void bind(final ProductItem item) {
            btnAddToBasket.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    item.clicked = true;
                    item.atomic.incrementAndGet();

                    Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, "New product..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    MyBasketFragment.myBasketList
                            .add(new ProductItem(item.getProductName(), item.getProductQuantity(),
                                    item.getproductPrice(), item.getThumbUrl(), id, shopCode));
                }
            });

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    ItemsFragment.atomic.incrementAndGet();
                    btnAddToBasket.setText(String.valueOf(atomic.get()));
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ProductItem itemPrice = data.get(position);
        holder.productName.setText(itemPrice.getProductName());
        holder.quantity.setText(itemPrice.getProductQuantity());
        holder.tvPrice.setText(itemPrice.getproductPrice());
        Picasso.with(fragmentActivity).load(itemPrice.getThumbUrl()).into(holder.imgProduct);

        holder.bind(itemPrice);

        if(itemPrice.clicked){
            holder.btnAddToBasket.setOnClickListener(null);

            holder.btnAddToBasket.setText(String.valueOf(atomic.get()));
            holder.btnAdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btnRemove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            holder.btnAddToBasket.setText("\uf291");
            holder.btnAdd.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.btnRemove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `getAdapterPosition()` is causing the problem. Please, try creating a new int attribute `position` in the viewholder, `onBindViewHolder` pass the the position to the viewholder, `holder.position = position`, and in your viewholder use the position, so will be `int pos = position` instead of `getAdapterPosition()`